# Sonarqube StyleCop analysis for c# multi-module project using Maven aggregator from Jenkins

Tags: c#, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, stylecop

I have a C# multimodule project that I want to run SonarQube analysis on. This project is built using Maven via an aggregator pom file. The sonar analysis works just fine, the modules are found and the sonar analysis completes. However, I don't see any StyleCop violation. For example

```
[INFO] [14:41:01.053] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.stylecop.StyleCopSensor@1d5df31...
[INFO] [14:41:01.148] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.18408
[INFO] [14:41:01.149] [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18444]
[INFO] [14:41:01.149] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[INFO] [14:41:01.149] 
[INFO] [14:41:01.189] Build started 21/11/2014 14:41:01.
[INFO] [14:41:01.410] Project "C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx\xxx\trunk\src\target\sonar\StyleCop-msbuild.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
[INFO] [14:41:01.411] StyleCopLaunch:
[INFO] [14:41:01.411]   No violations encountered
[INFO] [14:41:01.416] Done Building Project "C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx\xxx\trunk\src\target\sonar\StyleCop-msbuild.proj" (default targets).
[INFO] [14:41:01.421] 
[INFO] [14:41:01.421] Build succeeded.
[INFO] [14:41:01.421]     0 Warning(s)
[INFO] [14:41:01.421]     0 Error(s)
[INFO] [14:41:01.422] 
[INFO] [14:41:01.422] Time Elapsed 00:00:00.24
[INFO] [14:41:01.662] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.stylecop.StyleCopSensor@1d5df31 done: 609 ms
```

If I run the each module individually in a different Jenkins job, I see all the violations, including StyleCop ones, so the problem comes when I use the aggregator pom. I am using the following plugins in SonarQube

- C# 3.3
- Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects 1.2

The sonar properties are

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
sonar.exclusions=**/Reference.cs,**/*.designer.cs,**/*.Designer.cs,**/*.g.cs,**/target/**
sonar.stylecop.projectFilePath=trunk/src/
```

I am force to specify `projectFilePath` because if I don't the analysis just fails. With *Bootstrapper* enabled I would think the project files are detected automatically. Is there another way to specify the `projectFilePath` for each module? They all are under the same folder structure `trunk/src/`.

I have also tried defining the modules separately as it is done [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/b22bcd7fc29e01a2cc402eb9e14aef22443d8a81/projects/languages/csharp/sonar-project-without-visual-studio-bootstrapper.properties) with no luck. I've been trying to achieve this for two day and I don't know what else to try.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Analyzing .NET solutions with Maven, while perhaps technically possible, is not supported. I would recommend that you switch to the sonar-runner, post the analysis logs and your sonar-project.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the VS bootstrapper and use Core C# settings

```
# Core CSharp settings
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=mySolution.sln
sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies=*Test*.dll
sonar.skippedModules=TestProject1,TestProject2

# VS Bootstrapper settings
sonar.visualstudio.enable=false 

# Scan Directories
sonar.projectBaseDir=SourceDirectory
sonar.dotnet.assemblies=OutputDirectory\.
sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies=OutputDirectory\
```

This would by default use the sonar rules to analyze your code (.cs) files. You can choose StyleCop / FxCop / Resharper optionally and add them in settings file as well.

Comment: Why would you do that? BTW sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file is deprecated now